# Grafanas visualisations "graph" does not show lines, other visualisations do work

Tags: mysql, mariadb, grafana

I use recent Grafana 6.7 and try to display data from MariaDB. The "default" visualisation "Graph" does show correct x-axis and "wrong" y-axis ticks labels but not graph/lines. The "shown" information is wrong by factor of 1000.

If I chose other visalisations like "table" or "Gauge" the data is displayed as it is storred in the DB. Do you have any idea what goes wrong?

[image: Grafana dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by **removing** the default where condition "Macro: $_timeFilter". I thought this is necessary for time sliding or selecting. I wonder why it is there in the first place.

[image]